# WGET only the file names in an FTP directory

Tags: ftp, wget

I am attempting to create a dynamic list of files available in an ftp directory. I assume `wget` can help with this but I'm not really sure how...so my question is:

What is the syntax for retrieving file names from an ftp directory using `wget`?

Comment: Belongs to http://superuser.com/

Comment: Your question is off-topic here and should be asked on http://superuser.com

Comment: Oh ok...I'll look up the difference

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just execute

```
wget --no-remove-listing ftp://myftpserver/ftpdirectory/
```

This will generate two files: `.listing` (this is what you are looking for) and `index.html` which is the html version of the listing file.

Comment: Adding --spider will not download any page.

Comment: Sometimes it will take 10 seconds to download the .listing file and other times I left it for 10 minuets and I end up having to kill the process. The ftp site is: ftp://garner.ucsd.edu/pub/rinex/2001/001/ Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having more problems with other folders on that server. Could it be a server issue?