# wget getting 0-byte "listing" files from cleo vltrader

Tags: ftp, cygwin, wget

I am having trouble with wget and a particular ftp server. The problem is that when wget requests a file listing, it comes back as 0 bytes. I can get the listing fine with Filezilla v3.5.3 and FireFTP v2.0.4.

My wget is v1.13.4 running on Cygwin v1.7.15 / Windows XP. The ftp server identifies itself as "Linux Version: Cleo VLTrader/4.2.79 FTP server".

If I can't get a file listing, I won't be able to automate my download process. How can I fix this?

Transcript follows.

```
531 $ wget --user=**** --password=**** ftp://b2b.parkcitygroup.com/outbound/sales/
--2012-06-08 16:40:09--  ftp://b2b.parkcitygroup.com/outbound/sales/
           => `.listing'
Resolving b2b.parkcitygroup.com (b2b.parkcitygroup.com)... 205.132.39.56
Connecting to b2b.parkcitygroup.com (b2b.parkcitygroup.com)|205.132.39.56|:21... connected.
Logging in as ***** ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /outbound/sales ... done.
==> PASV ... done.    ==> LIST ... done.

    [ <=>                                                      ] 0           --.-K/s   in 0s

2012-06-08 16:40:11 (0.00 B/s) - `.listing' saved [0]

Unsupported listing type, trying Unix listing parser.
Removed `.listing'.
Wrote HTML-ized index to `index.html' [244].
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7261261) might be helpful: `wget --no-remove-listing ftp://myftpserver/ftpdirectory/`.