# How to list all files on a websites directory?

Tags: html, wget

Is there a way to list all files on a website or a websites subdirectory.

For instance if a website has

index.html
folder/hello.html

Is it possible to list those files?

Furthermore, is it possible to look for files that are not linked to anymore?

What about files of a specific type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WGET only the file names in an FTP directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261140/wget-only-the-file-names-in-an-ftp-directory)

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no way to interrogate a web server to find out information about the file system of the computer it is running on.

The closest you are going to get are:

- `/sitemap.xml` may contain a list of documents that the site owner wishes to promote to search engines.
- Some web servers are configured to generate an HTML document listing the files in a directory if a URL maps onto a directory on the file system that doesn't include a DirectoryIndex file.